# How to close IFeedback in Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket, feedback

I have an `IFeedback` component on my html, and it shows messages if something happens, etc: I upload a file, and a message will inform me: `1 file upload successfully`. And what I want is to close this message peace. How could I do it? If I refresh the page, the message will disappear, but I want to create a button, or a link, to click on it, and than the message will close/disappear. Can anyone give me an example, or some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `AjaxEventBehavior` that add's a `click` handler to your component and when it's clicked it will disappear. Here example code with an `FeedbackPanel`:

```
private FeedbackPanel feedbackPanel() {
    final FeedbackPanel fb = new FeedbackPanel("feedbackPanel") {
        @Override
        protected void onConfigure() {
            super.onConfigure();
            setVisible(anyMessage());
        }
    };
    fb.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("click") {
        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
          fb.setVisible(false);
          target.add(fb);
        }
    });
    fb.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
    return fb;
}
```

Comment: WebMarkupContainer which wraps the List with FeedbackMessages in the FeedbackPanel overwrites already the method "onConfigure", so you don't have to do this.
IMHO there is no need to explicitly set the visibility for the FeedbackPanel: on the subsequent ajax request (so when you want to hide the list), all FeedbackMessages are already mark as rendered and the list should disappear. Adding the FeedbackPanel to AjaxRequestTarget should be enough.

Comment: I think OP wanted to hide single messages in the FeedbackPanel, but your solution hides the entire Panel. You need to overwrite 'newMessageDisplayComponent' and add the 'AjaxEventBehavior' there.

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I do not need the `fb.setVisible(false);` line, because after I click on it, it will disappear, and than new message won't come up. So I only have to add to the `AjaxRequestTarget`! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You can close the item in a "regular" way by attaching Wicket `AjaxLink` to it and
setting the visibility to false onClick (you need to add the item to
AjaxRequestTarget). The method has one disadvantage: You need two Ajax calls.
One to show the IFeedbck item and the second to close it.

Another way to implement this is by adding custom AJAX call listener (in javascript).
Subscribe to the global event `'/ajax/call/success'`:

```
Wicket.Event.subscribe('/ajax/call/success',
    function(jqEvent, attributes, jqXHR, errorThrown, textStatus) {
        attachCloseHandler();
    }
);
```

and implement `attachCloseHandler()` function to attach close handlers to
your IFeedback items. In the most general case this is just something like:

```
$('#my-container-with-feedback-items .my-feedback-item').click( function(e) { 
// close the item 
});
```

You should check `'/ajax/call/success'` callback to see if the event relates to the feedback item to avoid calling the function every time.

The second implementation makes only one Ajax call: When the item gets rendered. The closing is done
only in javascript and you don't have additional Ajax call.

Reference: http://wicket.apache.org/guide/guide/chapter17.html#chapter17_5